# React Native: Unable to resolve module. None of these file exist:

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation-drawer

I am a beginner in React Native so I apologize if this is a noob question. I am trying to learn using [this react navigation article](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/) and [this about react login example](https://aboutreact.com/react-native-login-and-signup/#Project-DirectoryFile-Structure). The first article places all the code in `App.js` while the second one has code in separate pages but is slightly outdated. So my plan was to integrate both examples, using the first article's code but in separate pages instead of putting everything in `App.js`.

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMT5d.png)

The error I got:

```
None of these files exist:
  * Screen\drawerScreens\settingsScreen(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * Screen\drawerScreens\settingsScreen\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
   6 |
   7 | import HomeScreen from './Screen/drawerScreens/HomeScreen';
>  8 | import SettingsScreen from './Screen/drawerScreens/settingsScreen';
     |                             ^
```

Some help and tips would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if more information is required. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your project structure, I could see S is caps in **SettingsScreen** but you have imported as `settingsScreen` instead of `SettingsScreen`

so try importing as

```java
import SettingsScreen from './Screen/drawerScreens/SettingsScreen';
```

Comment: As embarrassing it is to admit this, but yes that seemed to fix the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool, It happens to me also sometimes 

Answer (score 4):

The solution for me was reset the **react-native** cache with the command.

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if it is exported as default or export const, if it is the 2nd one, then use import { SettingsScreen } instead of import SettingsScreen

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes If you don't find any error, then kill the Metro and terminal and just restart. It might resolve that error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the file extension ?

Ex. './Screen/drawerScreens/settingsScreen.js'

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried adding the file extensions but sadly it didn't work. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I copied and dropped the file from Finder (mac). It added an extra space to the end of that folder name. Erase that space worked.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file you are trying to import must start with a capital letter.

If your filename is "settings.js", React will not detect it.

Change the filename to "Settings.js".

I think this is because its a React rule that all components name must start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if related but i had similar issue by default i'm offered import as

`'src/Button.tsx'`

but i need to change this manually to

`'../../Button.tsx'`